# Проверка на количество чисел стоящие рядом. Python

Tags: python

Вводится натуральное число. Необходимо проверить, есть ли в этом числе какие-то две одинаковые стоящие рядом цифры. Вывести эти цифры, если таковые имеются, иначе вывести «НЕТ».

```py
a = int(input("a = "))
a1 = a % 10
a = a // 10
k = 0
while a>0:
    a2 = a % 10
    if a1==a2:
       k+=1
       a = a // 10
       a1 = a2
       if k>0:
           print("Yes")
       else:
           print("Нет")
```

Comment: вы пробовали выполнить задание? можно увидеть вашу попытку?

Comment: можно не переводить в целое число, а сравнивать символы. т.е. проходить по строке и сравнивать рядом идущие символы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цифра это символ а не число. Не обязательно заниматься математикой для сравнения символов

```
import functools

def siblings(a,b):
    if a[0] and a[0]==b:
        print(a[0],b,sep='')
        a[1]+=1
    return [b, a[1]]


s="12334513"

last, num = functools.reduce(siblings, s, [None,0])

if num==0: print("HET")
```

У Вас ошибка в отступах на `if k>0:` и на `a = a // 10`

```
a = int(input("a = "))
a1 = a % 10
a = a // 10
k = 0
while a>0:
    a2 = a % 10
    if a1==a2:
        k+=1
    a = a // 10
    a1 = a2
    
    
if k>0:
   print("Yes")
else:
   print("Нет")
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант ещё код с параллельной итерацией по числу-строке со сдвигом. Мне кажется такой код гораздо понятнее других:

```
def test_num(num):
    for a, b in zip(num, num[1:]):
        if a == b:
            print(a)
            return
    print('НЕТ')

test_num('')
test_num('12345')
test_num('1233')
```

Вывод:

```
НЕТ
НЕТ
3
```